# MGT Development Environment Permissions 777 corret?

Tags: magento, docker, permissions

Permissions are wrong when instantiating to 777 for bulk folders. How to fix this?

MGTDevelopmentEnvironment

SO Mac

Comment: what are you asking?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?